# How do I stop gradle from upgrading transitive dependencies?

Tags: gradle, spring-security, grails-4

Why is Gradle changing my library's transitive dependency to a newer version? How do I get it to stop?

**Details**

I am working on an internal plugin library for my company that uses Spring Security. The plugin explicitly declares a dependency on the latest version of Spring Security 4:

```
    compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.13.RELEASE') {
        force = true
    }
```

When I include the plugin in a client project, Gradle is upgrading me from spring security 4 to 5, which breaks the plugin.

```
    compile 'com.mycompany:my-security-plugin:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Here is the output from dependencyInsight in the client project:

```
> Task :dependencyInsight
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.1.6.RELEASE (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status             = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage              = java-api
      org.gradle.component.category = library (not requested)
   ]

org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.1.6.RELEASE
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.1.6.RELEASE
|    \--- com.mycompany:my-security-plugin:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT:20200122.162056-4 (requested org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.13.RELEASE)
|         \--- compileClasspath
\--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.1.6.RELEASE
     \--- com.mycompany:my-security-plugin:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT:20200122.162056-4 (requested org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.13.RELEASE) (*)

org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE
\--- com.mycompany:my-security-plugin:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT:20200122.162056-4
     \--- compileClasspath
```

It looks to me like in all cases, I am requesting spring security 4 in my config. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Gradle 5.1.1.

**Update**

As a workaround, it is possible to have the client app declare a direct dependency on spring security, using a specific version. I'm trying to avoid this, if possible.

**Update 2**

Output from `gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.springframework.security:spring-security-web`:

```
> Task :dependencyInsight
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.1.6.RELEASE (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status             = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage              = java-api
      org.gradle.component.category = library (not requested)
   ]

org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE
\--- com.mycompany:my-security-plugin:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT:20200122.162056-4
     \--- compileClasspath
```

**Update 3**

The buildEnvironment includes the following, via grails:

```
 +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.9.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:2.1.9.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.8.RELEASE
```

Comment: Something else seems to be introducing `org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.1.6.RELEASE` (I'm guessing from `(*)` as a hint), that in turn could be introducing the `org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.1.6.RELEASE` which is causing to omit your lib dependency. Could you perform `dependencyInsight` on `org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.1.6.RELEASE` and post the output?

Comment: Posted the output. Thanks

Comment: Aparently your plugin is being used in a project that uses a newer Spring Security version. Forcing your version of Spring security will break that project. Either that project has to downgrade its dependendencies or you have to upgrade them in yours (or make them work with both versions of Spring Security)!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming that you use the Spring Dependency Management Plugin (`io.spring.dependency-management`) and maybe also the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin (`org.springframework.boot`)? Then it’s very likely that this combination will also manage the eventual version of `spring-security-core` for you, irrespective of what other pieces of your build setup request.

## Minimal Setup Demonstrating the Problem

I have the following two Gradle builds sitting next to each other (omitting the Gradle 5.1.1 Wrapper files for brevity):

```
my-security-plugin
└── build.gradle
my-client
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

Running the following Gradle command from within `my-client` gives me (roughly) the same output as in the OP’s question:

```
./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency org.springframework.security:spring-security-core
```

### `my-security-plugin/build.gradle`

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.mycompany'
version = '0.3.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.13.RELEASE') {
        force = true
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.13.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.13.RELEASE'
}
```

### `my-client/build.gradle`

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.mycompany'
version = '1.0.0'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'com.mycompany:my-security-plugin:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

### `my-client/settings.gradle`

```java
includeBuild '../my-security-plugin'
```

This file is only here to define a Gradle composite build; `includeBuild` won’t be there in the production build, you will rather publish the `my-security-plugin` to some repository from where `my-client` downloads it.

## Possible Solutions to the Problem

As mentioned in the introduction, the combination of Spring Dependency Management Plugin and Spring Boot Gradle Plugin defines the version of `spring-security-core` for your build. Aside from your own workaround, there are three possibilities to get to the version you want:

1. Use the Spring Boot version that selects the same version of `spring-security-core` that you need: `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.22.RELEASE'`
2. [Customize the managed versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html//#managing-dependencies-customizing) by setting an extra property in your build: `ext['spring-security.version'] = '4.2.13.RELEASE'`
3. Don’t let Spring manage your dependencies at all …

All these solutions obviously have drawbacks:

- solution 1 forces you to use an old Spring Boot version
- solution 2 forces you to request the required version of a transitive dependency in your client app (which is similar to your own workaround that you wanted to avoid)
- solution 3 may not be worth the extra work that manually managing all Spring dependencies would incur

Now you only have to choose the lesser evil ;-)